# Facebook login/logout buttons on Facebook App using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an app on my website that uses facebook to post photos my facebook albums using PHP.

I would like to further enhance it by doing the following:

1. In order to use the app - I would like a login/logout (I think this can be done but I do not know how)
2. In order for the visitors to use the app the would have to have pressed 'Like' on my page to use this app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link for the PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Here's a link for the most basic example: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

And here's a link for the facebook SDK documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

You can use the most basic example - it does the login and logout and upgrade it to sute your needs. In two words: it has a login and logout URL, the data is stored in sessions. You just have to use the open graph to check if the user has liked your page.